# Expanding a tight-binding hamiltonian around a Dirac point (1.D. Graphene)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, second-quantization, graphene, tight-binding

My off diagonal terms for this Hamiltonian are the following:

$H = e^{\mp ik_xa}(1+ 2e^{\pm i3k_xa/2}\cos(\sqrt{3}k_ya/2)) $

Next, I want to see the low energy bands, and for this I've been told to expand the Hamiltonian near the corners of the first Brillouin zone. For the two unique corners I got,

$K = \frac{2 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}a}\left(\sqrt{3}, \pm1 \right)$

Now, I am having problems in the next step. I want to expand this Hamiltonian by using the crystalline quasi-momentum,
$\vec{k} = \vec{K} + \vec{q}$

What I did on pen and paper, was to replace all $\vec{k_x},\vec{k_y}$'s with the expression above. Then I proceeded to expand the terms that included $\vec{q}_i$, to first order. I know that I am supposed to get some linear expression of both $q_x$ and $q_y$, but I am having trouble with actually computing the taylor expansion around the $q$ points.

I have spent an absurd amount of time trying to calculate this so any recommendations or resources would be greatly appreciated.

The actual low-energy Hamiltonian should be of the following form,
$\Delta_{K + q}- i e^{-i K_x a}\frac{3a}{2}(q_x + iq_y) $

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but in your original Hamiltonian, the factor $a$ appears to be used inconsistently in the arguments of the complex exponentials.  In the first term of the product, $a$ is in the numerator, and the second term it is in the denominator.  It might be worth a quick double check to see that the derivation of the Hamiltonian is correct.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @ad2004 Thanks for catching that, it was actually a typo. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The off-diagonal terms can be reorganized into the form:

$H_{od}=e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\delta_1}}+e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\delta_2}}+e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\delta_3}}$

with $\vec{\delta_1}=(-a,0)$, $\vec{\delta_2}=(\frac{1}{2}a,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a)$, and $\vec{\delta_3}=(\frac{1}{2}a,-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a)$

Now let $\vec{k}=\vec{K}+\vec{q}$, we can easily expand the exponential term as:

$e^{i(\vec{K}+\vec{q})\cdot\vec{\delta}}=e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta}}e^{i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{\delta}}=e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta}}(1+i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{\delta}+o(q^2))$

Thus the off-diagonal term can be expanded as (to the linear order of $q$):

$H_{od}=(e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_1}}+e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_2}}+e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_3}})+e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_1}}(i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{\delta_1})+e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_2}}(i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{\delta_2})+e^{i\vec{K}\cdot\vec{\delta_3}}(i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{\delta_3})$

Substituting the values of $K$s and $\delta$s, you can get the final answer.

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten to answer this question.